# Filling null values within a Pandas DataFrame with values from the same column that have a matching value in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, null, series

I have a DataFrame that has nulls within a given column, within the same index, there is another column with repeating non Null values. What I am trying to figure out is what's the proper way of filling those null values using the ID column as reference using Pandas native functions.

Thank you for your help.

Original:

```
    Company ID
    AAA 100
    BBB 200
    CCC 150
    **NULL  100
    FFF 375
    **NULL  150
```

Formatted:

```
    AAA 100
    BBB 200
    CCC 150
    **AAA   100
    FFF 375
    **CCC   150
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Company'] = df.groupby('ID')['Company'].transform('first')
```

---

As commented, the above will replace **all** `Company` not just those with `nan`. So it may give wrong result if you have several `Company` for an `ID`. Instead, you can do:

```
df['Company'] = df['Company'].fillna(df.groupby('ID')['Company'].transform('first'))
```

Comment: I think this would transform all the rows having the same value and not necesseraly just those having null value.

Comment: @AyoubZAROU That is true. I was under the impression that `Company` should be unique for each `ID`. But this can be fixed easily.